# What is the tradeoff of creating too many database indexes?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a Python crawler that runs forever.

This is the problem at hand:

```
# Time: 151201 19:36:18
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 25.516377  Lock_time: 0.000059 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 55589711
SET timestamp=1449016578;
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  *  FROM  `links`  WHERE  `URL`  LIKE  '%http://www.smallbizpages.ca/%' LIMIT 1;
# Time: 151201 19:37:01
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 32.796236  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 13245375
SET timestamp=1449016621;
SELECT * FROM links WHERE URL LIKE '%smallbizpages.ca%' ORDER BY dateChecked ASC LIMIT 50;
```

Query times of 25-32 seconds is really slowing down the other scripts and threads.

My schema:

[image]

My indexes:

[image]

I have everything set as an index, but it still runs so slow. Is there too many indexes? Not enough?

The program essentially does a select, then an insert and repeats.

Answer (score 3):

When you insert a row, the value must be added to the index.

When you delete a row, the value must be removed from the index.

When you update a value in a column that is indexed, the value must be updated in the index.

Get rid of the leading '%' in your LIKE clauses too.

Your best bet is to get your execution plan and see why it's slow (you could post another question with your execution plan. Probably get better results on dba stack exchange).

Comment: So do you think I should group together all of my inserts?

Comment: Batch inserts might help ya.

Answer (score 2):

`column LIKE '%whatever%'` cannot use an index. How could it? So it reverts to a full scan.

On the other hand, decent SQL databases are able to use an index for `column LIKE 'whatever%'`, which is probably a lot more relevant in your case.

Beyond that, you probably need to split the URL in scheme/host/path and normalise that so you can easily get all requests for a given host. Also, a 255 char limit for an URL will get you into trouble.

Comment: So you're saying have 3 columns to split the URL across?

Comment: At least, but I would go further and use multiple tables, at least one for host (possibly including scheme) and one for URL which references the host table. Then you can add multi-column indexes on host_id,path and host_id,dateChecked

Comment: @User, if the answer helped you, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.